# Extraer Html con css inline con Open-Xml-PowerTools

Tags: html, c#, xml

Estoy tratando de extraer html de un archivo de word, pero el archivo final coloca todos los estilos en una etiqueta style, como puedo extraer html con los estilos inline?

este en mi codigo

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"file.docx");
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
            {
                HtmlConverterSettings settings = new HtmlConverterSettings()
                {
                    PageTitle = "My Page Title"
                };
                XElement html = HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(doc, settings);

                File.WriteAllText(@"index.html", html.ToStringNewLineOnAttributes());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Se que open xml construye el archivo de word basado en xml, pero de ahi a tener un html, no lo entiendo. Estas seguro que un docx se puede convertir a html. Se que un documento se puede guardar como html, pero no convertir como lo planteas

Comment: puede probar el código por favor.